# PHP Array to JSON Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following PHP array:

```
array(3) {
  ["NDQ"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Google"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Yahoo"
  }
  ["NYSE"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "3M Co"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "Abbott Laboratories"
  }
  ["FX"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "Euro vs US Dollar"
  }
}
```

I want to save this as a JSON document so I do the follwoing:

```
$instrument_names = json_encode($instrument_names, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
file_put_contents("../data/instrument_names.json", $instrument_names);
```

But the JSON file I get is as follows:

```
{
    "NDQ":
    {
        "0":"Google",
        "1":"Yahoo"
    },

    "NYSE":
    {
        "0":"3M Co",
        "1":"Abbott Laboratories"
    },

    "FX":
    {
        "0":"Euro vs US Dollar"
    }
}
```

where each name has been given a key as the index of the array (which was sequentially numbered).

How do I turn this into an array instead?

```
"NDQ":
{
    ["Google","Yahoo"]
}
```

Comment: Remove JSON_FORCE_OBJECT?

Comment: @Savvas, Woudn't that format break your JSON ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, what would be wrong with the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

As someone kindly pointed out:

I was using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT option that forces sequential arrays to be JSON objects.

When I removed this, it worked fine.